# Why is the unit vector negative when solving $\sin(a-b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) - \cos(a)\sin(b)$?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, cross-product

given the graph [image]

Use the cross product $U\times V$ to prove the identity 
$$\sin(a-b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) - \cos(a)\sin(b).$$

I tried to solve but ended with the solution  $\sin(a-b) = \cos(a)\sin(b) - \sin(a)\cos(b)$ with the work i did provided below

$$\begin{split}
U\times V &= |U||V| \sin(a-b) e \\
U\times V &= (|U||V|) \sin(a-b) \frac{U \times V}{|U\times V|}\\
\frac{|U\times V|}{|U||V|} &= \sin(a - b)\\
\frac{U_x V_y - U_yV_x}{|U||V|}&= \sin(a-b)\\
\frac{\cos(a)U \sin(b)V - \sin(a)U \cos(b)V}{|U||V|}&= \sin(a-b) \\
\cos(a) \sin(b) - \sin(a) \cos(b)) &= \sin(a-b).
\end{split}$$

Comment: If $a$ is $\theta_1$ and $b$ is $\theta_2$ in this diagram, and $e$ is the unit vector in the $z$-direction then $u\times v$ is the **negative** of what you have written (by right-hand rule). Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference